# How to join SQL statements with different where clause on different column of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have 3 queries in sql:

1st query:

```
select t1ID ,AVG(t2score) AS AVG1
from T1
WHERE t1m1 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m2 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3)
group by t1ID
```

Result

```
+------+------+
| t1ID | AVG1 |
+------+------+
|    1 |   55 |
|    2 |   45 |
|    3 |   73 |
|    4 |   69 |
+------+------+
```

2nd query :

```
select t1ID ,AVG(t2score) AS AVG2
from T1
WHERE t1m2 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m1 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3)
group by t1ID
```

Result

```
+------+------+
| t1ID | AVG2 |
+------+------+
|    1 | 68   |
|    2 | 56   |
|    3 | NULL |
|    4 | NULL |
+------+------+
```

3rd query

```
select t1ID ,AVG(t2score) AS AVGt3
from T1
WHERE t1m3 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m1 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3)
group by t1ID
```

Result

```
+------+------+
| t1ID | AVG3 |
+------+------+
|    1 | NULL |
|    2 | 70   |
|    3 | NULL |
|    4 | NULL |
+------+------+
```

How can I combine these three statements so that I get these results added together like this ( each AVG score in different column)

Desired Result:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| t1ID | AVG1 | AVG2 | AVG3 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |   55 | 68   | NULL |
|    2 |   45 | 56   | 70   |
|    3 |   73 | NULL | NULL |
|    4 |   69 | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: are the contents of your IN clauses literals or column identifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional aggregation mentioned in the comments works by placing a `CASE` expression inside the `AVG()` function call, so averaging only values that meet specific criteria...

```
SELECT
   t1ID,
   AVG(CASE WHEN t1m1 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m1 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) THEN t2Score END)   AVG1,
   AVG(CASE WHEN t1m2 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m1 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) THEN t2Score END)   AVG2,
   AVG(CASE WHEN t1m3 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m1 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) THEN t2Score END)   AVG3
FROM
    T1
GROUP BY
    t1ID
```

This works because anything that fails the conditions in the `CASE` expression return a `NULL`, and all the aggregation functions such as `AVG()` effectively ignore `NULL`s.

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: @Jodrell - This is a single scan of the full table.  The alternative is three scans of portions of the table.  If those portions are easy to identify *(indexes)* ***and*** are significantly smaller than 1/3rd of the table, then separate queries *could* be faster.  In which case I would `UNION` and aggregate the results of the three queries, rather than `JOIN` them.

Comment: After thinking about, I strongly suspect this is the best approach. It must be better than `LEFT JOIN`s to sub queries or UNIONS, right?

Comment: @MatBailie I agree, your answer is better for the general case.

Answer (score 0):

You may use CTE to achieve the output. Like this-

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
    select t1ID ,AVG(t2score) AS AVG1
    from T1
    WHERE t1m1 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m2 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3)
    group by t1ID

 ),
 cte2 AS
 (
    select t1ID ,AVG(t2score) AS AVG2
    from T1
    WHERE t1m2 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m1 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3)
    group by t1ID
 ),
 cte3 as
 (
     select t1ID ,AVG(t2score) AS AVGt3
     from T1
     WHERE t1m3 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m1 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3)
     group by t1ID
)
SELECT cte1.t1ID, cte1.AVG1, cte2.AVG2, cte3.AVG3
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2 ON cte1.t1ID = cte2.t1ID
JOIN cte3 ON cte2.t1ID = cte3.t1ID
```

> This is appropriate **ONLY** if `t1ID` column returns always all IDs in each query.

In other words (as of [MatBailie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie))

> This is only appropriate if the `WHERE` clauses in the sub-queries never
>   filter out any of the requisite `t1ID` values.

Comment: Your caveat would be better to say : This is only appropriate if the `WHERE` clauses in the sub-queries never filter out any of the requisite `t1ID` values.  *(It's the behaviour of the `WHERE` clause that matters...)*

Comment: Also, please don't use `cte1, cte2, cte2`, please actually use `JOIN` notation.

Comment: why favour a CTE over a subquery?

Comment: The idea is okay. However, comma separated joins were made redundant in 1992. Please don't use them anymore. What you actually need for the query to work properly is full outer joins. Multiple full outer joins on the same column(s) are a bit clumsy in SQL Server, though, for the lack of the `USING` clause.

Comment: @Jodrell: Performance would be same in this case. It's more readable.

Comment: @Shanid readability is subjective, personally I find CTEs make statements harder to read, they make sense when the CTE is reused in the statement. It is not true that CTEs have equivalent performance to sub-queries, this will depend on the query plan that is generated, CTEs can result in a different query plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `SELECT` of just the ids and then (`LEFT`) `JOIN` the subquerys on the ids like this:

```
select t1ID, AVG1, AVG2, AVG3 FROM 
(SELECT t1ID FROM T1 GROUP BY t1ID) AS IDs
JOIN (select t1ID ,AVG(t2score) AS AVG1
from T1
WHERE t1m1 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m2 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3)
group by t1ID) AS group1 USING (t1ID)
JOIN (select t1ID ,AVG(t2score) AS AVG2
from T1
WHERE t1m2 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m1 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3)
group by t1ID) AS group2 USING (t1ID)
JOIN (select t1ID ,AVG(t2score) AS AVG3
from T1
WHERE t1m3 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m1 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3)
group by t1ID) AS group3 USING (t1ID)
```

You have to give each subquery a table alias.

Comment: Joining all the results to the `t1` table assumes that `t1ID` is unique in the `t1` table.  If that were the case, the `AVG()` would be pointless, due to it only ever processing single rows...

Comment: You are right, there must be a group also in the outer statement.

Comment: Now you have a syntax error, because you're selecting `AVG1` but neither grouping by it, nor aggregating it.  Better to use `(SELECT t1ID FROM t1 GROUP BY t1ID) AS t1 JOIN ...`

Comment: I don't see where there is a syntax error. Of course I can select something I do not group on. But your approach has better perfomance.

Comment: No, you can't.  `SELECT a, b, c, d FROM x GROUP BY a` is a syntax error.  `SELECT a, b, c, d FROM x GROUP BY a, b, c, d` is valid, `SELECT a, MAX(b), MAX(c), MAX(d) FROM x GROUP BY a` is valid.  Try it yourself *(even MySQL throws an error now-days with the default settings, and SQL Server will **always** throw an error.)*

Comment: Ok, I thought of MySQL but my Server (5.7.22) does not throw an error. It is only not determined, which of the b,c,d values you get through the query.

Comment: Perhaps actually read the manual?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Thanks for poiting this out. I was not aware, that this is a feature of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
{SELECT t1ID, AVG(FirstT.t2score) AS AVG1, AVG(SecondT.t2score) AS AVG1, AVG(ThirdT.t2score) AS AVG1
FROM T1 t
JOIN T1 FirstT ON FirstT.t1ID = t.t1ID AND FirstT.t1m1 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) AND FirstT.t1m2 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3)
JOIN T1 SecondT ON SecondT.t1ID = t.t1ID AND SecondT.t1m2 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) AND SecondT.t1m1 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3)
JOIN T1 ThirdT ON ThirdT.t1ID = t.t1ID AND FirstT.t1m3 NOT IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3) and t1m1 IN (t2m1,t2m2,t2m3)enter code here
GROUP BY t1ID}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

creating temporary table and inserting data to it may help you

Comment: this is a comment not an answer also, not a very constructive comment unless you know something I don't.